# SQLITE Query the same table twice and put these queries into two different columns?

Tags: sqlite

My question is how to do two select statements and have the results in separate colummns?

For Example,

My statements are

```
Select count(*) as "JAN" from tickets where created_at BETWEEN "2015-01-01" AND "2015-01-31"
Select count(*) as "FEB" from tickets where created_at BETWEEN "2015-02-01" AND "2015-02-25"
```

I have tried placing a comma and putting the second statements in parenthesis but that hasn't worked either. I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. Could anyone take a look at this? Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: you could do it with a join.

Comment: Joins work with the same tables? I was under the impression this only worked with a separate table.

Comment: @user614885 Yes, you can join with the same table more than once, usually using a different ON condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't even need a join, as SQLite support [CASE expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) :

```
select
sum(case 
    when created_at between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31' then 1
    else 0 end) as "JAN",
sum(case
    when created_at between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-25' then 1
    else 0 end) as "FEB"
from tickets
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the SELECTs into scalar subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tickets
        WHERE created_at GLOB '2015-01*-') AS "JAN",
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tickets
        WHERE created_at GLOB '2015-02-*') AS "FEB";
```